# Sql query performance difference between limit row count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a hug table with 170,000 records.

What is difference between this query

```
Showing rows 0 - 299 (1,422 total, Query took 1.9008 sec)
    SELECT 1 FROM `p_apartmentbuy` p 
    where 
    p.price between 500000000 and 900000000
    and p.yard = 1
    and p.dateadd between 1290000000 and 1320000000
    ORDER BY `p`.`id` desc
    limit 1669
```

Explain
[image]

And this one:

```
Showing rows 0 - 299 (1,422 total, Query took 0.2625 sec)
    SELECT 1 FROM `p_apartmentbuy` p 
    where 
    p.price between 500000000 and 900000000
    and p.yard = 1
    and p.dateadd between 1290000000 and 1320000000
    ORDER BY `p`.`id` desc
    limit 1670
```

Explain:
[image]

Both of these queries are using 1 table with same data and have same where clasue, but only limit row count are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has a buffer for sorting. When the stuff to be sorted is too big, it sorts chunks, then mergesorts them. This is called "filesort". Your 1670-th row apparently just overflows the sort buffer.

Read more details [here](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24).

Now why it picks another key for the in-memory sort... I am not too sure; but apparently its strategy is not quite good since it ends up being slower.

Comment: Is there also page caching in MySQL?  This is a common thing in SQL Server, where the second run is faster since the data is in memory.

Comment: tnx for answer. How i can disable this buffer for sorting?

Comment: You could set the `@@sort_buffer_size`, but that's a hack. One thing to try would be to `SELECT ... USE INDEX(yard)`, to make sure the faster strategy is used; see what `EXPLAIN` says about that.

Comment: @Amadan: i tested first query(2sec) SELECT ... USE INDEX(yard) ... LIMIT 1669. But this time query took was 0.2 sec

Comment: Sorry, seems I can't help you after all... :(

Comment: I cant understand properly why?, but it seems your answer is true, because i cant find any better result in my other research. thanks for answering :)

Comment: @JNK - Yes, there is caching.  1.9s vs 0.26s smells a lot like caching.  Hamid, run the queries twice to avoid the I/O that might be happening the first time.  On the other hand, the difference in the EXPLAINs is a good mystery.  And I believe it has _nothing_ to do with `sort_buffer_size`.

Comment: The first EXPLAIN decided to to a "table scan"; the second decided to use the "yard" index.  Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE, so we can see the indexes you have.  Then we may recommend better ones.  In particular, a _compound_ index _starting_ with `yard`, and having `price` or `dateadd` second is likely to be good.  Don't do FORCE INDEX.

Answer (score 1):

recap: odd that the query returning more rows runs much faster

this is not related to buffer vs file sort, sorting 1400 records takes well under 1 second

the first explain shows the query optimizer doing a linear scan, the second explain shows it using an index.  Even a partially helpful index is usually much better than none at all.

Internally, mysql maintains stats about the size of indexes and tries to guess which index, or whether a linear scan would be faster.  This estimate is data specific, I've seen mysql use the right index 99 times out of 100, but every now and then pick a different one and run the query 50x slower.

You can override the built-in query optimizer and specify the index to use manually, with SELECT ... FROM ... FORCE INDEX (...)